# Acknowledgment from Consumer in ActiveMQ

Tags: message-queue, activemq-classic, consumer

I want to acknowledge messages after they have been processed by some processing engine like yahoo! S4. I can only send the messages to the engine using a Adapter.

Currently I am storing each message in the adapter, till the processing engine returns me the JMScorrelationID of the message, telling that the message has been processed. But this takes up lot of space on the Adapter for storing each message.

So is there any way by which we can manually create the acknowledgement using the JMScorrelationID and send it to the broker??

Answer (score 0):

No, this sort of thing is not supported by the JMS spec.  You can use transactions and commit when your adapter has finished its work.